# Passing an object by reference to a function, unexpected behaviour

Tags: javascript, function, pass-by-reference, javascript-objects

So i  have this piece of code  where i try to mutate an object by passing it as a reference to a function:

```
var c = { why: 'older' };
var d;
d = c;
//passing by reference
function changeGreeting(obj) {
    obj.why = 'newer' ; // mutate         
}
changeGreeting(d)
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

This mutates successfully and outputs as expected :
[image]
No problems until so far..

Then i have the evil twin code looks the same but does't behave:

```
var c = { why: 'older' };
var d;
d = c;
//passing by reference, i wish..
function changeGreeting(obj) {
    obj = { why: 'newer' }; // trying to mutate..        
}
changeGreeting(d)
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
```

I would expect this to work the same way but it doesn't(it fails to mutate).
[image]
Looking for a good clear explanation why?

Comment: 1) Like Java, JavaScript has pass-by-value only. It has no pass-by-reference. 2) "objects" are not values cannot be passed; objects are always manipulated through references (pointers to objects) and you are passing a reference, by value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code `obj = { why: 'newer' };` does not mutate, it just assigns to a local variable `obj` inside your function.

To mutate the object, you need to use property assignment.

In other words, `obj` points to some object (contains a reference to that object), so you can mutate it. By reassigning the value to other object, you are replacing that reference to original object with reference to your new object.

Comment: yeah, now it all makes sense except "To mutate object reference, you can not use assignment."  Isn't : obj.why = 'newer' ; mutating object reference  by assignment? It successfully mutates and goes outside of function scope

Comment: @a1nb0 I fixed it. Martin, if you disagree please rollback

Comment: awesome, that makes a lot of sense thanks Martin and Bergi

Answer (score 1):

Your function basically behaves as following

```
function changeGreeting(obj) {
    var obj; // creates the local variable
    obj = d; // assign the arguments (objects are passed by reference)
    obj = { why: 'newer' }; // Creates new reference for local object        
}
```

Because of the above behavior, the references for `c` and `d` are preserved and continue to point to the same memory location before the function call.

**Edit**

The first scenario behaves like the following

```
function changeGreeting(obj) {
    var obj; // creates the local variable
    obj = d; // assign the arguments (objects are passed by reference)
    obj.why = 'newer'; // Updates local variable obj which has same reference as "d" and "c" 
}
```

Comment: yes, this also helped me to bring home the idea. What i would love to see still is what happens in the first example the one that successfully mutates. Why this one stays locally and the first one goes outside of function scope and mutates the object. This aspect is a bit fuzzy still

Comment: @a1nb0 - Added explanation for the first scenario as well. Hope it resolves your queries now.

Answer (score 0):

When you do 
    `obj = { why: 'newer' };`
You are modifying the function scoped variable `obj` to a reference to a new object `{ why: 'newer' }`.

Comment: yeah and that is why one stays locally and has no connection with the one outside of the function and fails to mutate. makes sense